# AX LCS - Azure configuration

Tags: azure

I have configuring the AX in LCS through Azure. During that environment deployment I am facing some issue as below

"The environment could not be deployed because your Azure subscription does not support additional cores. determine if there are any  existing virtual machines that you can delete.

Kindly help me how to fix this issue.

Thank You,
Kasthurirangan.V

Answer (score 0):

**Azure Portal**:
Subscriptions -> *Subscription Name* -> Usage + quotas

From within the selected blade, you'll be presented with the current resource usage of that specific subscription and the allowed current quotas.

Reading the error above, it's indicating you may reached the cores quota limit. To resolve this, you'll either need to Request an increase which is possible in the top right corner or you'll need to delete resources.